# Linux command error for renaming multiple files in folder

Tags: linux

I am using this command and `sample_numbers_names.csv` file to rename multiple files in the folder which has subfolders with different file names.

```
while IFS=, read -a p ; do SAMPLENUM=${p[0]} ; find . -type f -name "${SAMPLENUM}*" -exec rename -v "${SAMPLENUM}" "${p[1]}_${SAMPLENUM}" {} \; ; done < sample_numbers_names.csv
```

The csv file has two columns first for old name and next for the new name. for e.g.

```
111,abc
222,xyz
```

After using this command the out put I am getting is like this

`111.txt` is converted to `abc._111.txt`

How to remove that `dot` after abc so that renamed file will look like `abc_111.txt` rather than `abc._111.txt`

Comment: why `read -a`?  Seems much cleaner to write `read old new` use names instead of `${p[0]}` and `${p[1]}`

Comment: You are right, that's much cleaner, I've edited my answer below using your suggestion.

Comment: Its still not removing the `.` after names

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work as desired:

```
$ cat sample_numbers_names.csv 
111,abc
222,xyz
$ mkdir -p foo/bar
$ touch foo/bar/{111,222}.txt
$ while IFS=, read old new ; do find . -type f | xargs rename "s/${old}/${new}_${old}/"; done < sample_numbers_names.csv
$ ls foo/bar/
abc_111.txt  xyz_222.txt
```

Comment: I need `abc_111.txt` and `xyz_222.txt` as output

Comment: Its is not changing the file names if they are in the sub-folders.

Comment: For me it's working for subfolders, I've edited the example to reflect it. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: yes consider folder x with subfolders named a,b,c. Each subfolders a,b,c has random multiple files whose name I want to change based on .csv file. My command works except it adds "." after the name. Your command doesn't change the names of the files in subfolders.

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between your a,b,c subfolders and the foo/bar one in my working example. Could you please detail it with a specific example where my command does not work (contents of the csv file and path/filename of the files)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195713/discussion-between-ronick-and-jacalvo).